# Entity framework code-first connect server error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am new in Entity framework. I have a simple project using code-first approach.

This is codes:

```
 public class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
    }

   

    public class SchoolContext:DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext() : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student aa = new Student();
            aa.id=1 ;
            aa.StudentName = "eeee";
            using (var scContext = new SchoolContext())
            {
                scContext.Students.Add(aa);
                scContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            Console.Write("success");
        }
```

The connection string automatic create by Entity framework:

> *Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=EFExample.Model.SchoolContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True*

I installed sqlserver 2012 express, with 2 instances:

> NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
>
> NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

When i ran the program, i get an error :

```
*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL*
```

[image]

App.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Please help me what is wrong?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Please could you post the `<connectionStrings>` section of your `app.config`?

Comment: `(localdb)` usually refers to SQL Server LocalDB, which is a file based SQL database (like SqLite).  Try changing that to `Data Source=localhost\mssqllocaldb`.

Comment: @ Chris Pickford: i don't use connectionstring in app.config. I think EF will automatic create a connection string.

Comment: For SQLExpress instances I usually use this format: `<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>` Please check your `app.config` just to be sure.

Comment: Though it seems to be related with connStr as others said, could you also add Inner exception, just in case it might give us a clue.
Also, your casing is inconsistent. Some variables are camelCase and some are PascalCase. Better stick to either, preferably camelCase as it's considered to be standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest explicitly adding your own connectionstring in the app.config

```
`<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL_INSTANCE_NAME;Initial Catalog=DBName;Connection Timeout=60;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False" name="DbConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran into similar troubles, it seemed first to the sql server 2016 a setup problem, than some missing connection string in the web.config file.
for the code first in asp.net mvc one line made it:

public OdeToFoodDb() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {

Answer (score 0):

i ran into similar troubles, it seemed first to the sql server 2016 a setup problem, than some missing connection string in the web.config file.
for the code first in asp.net mvc one line made it:

e.g. my Model class is BeispielDb derived from DbContext
thereafter the 'ctor' has mandatory to invoke the base 'ctor' with the db connection string:

```
public BeispielDb() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
```

the constructor has fed the DbContext(base class) constructor with the DefaultConnection string from the web.config.

Have a nice day and keep well,

Salomon MOYAL-BLOCH